# Any way to make an image round in Konvajs?

Tags: konvajs

I have a Konva image. How do I set radius or border-radius?

In the docs the Image class has width and height, but I want to set the Radius (border-radius). There is a circle class that can have an image as a background. However, when I use this you need to specify the dimensions for each image to make it zoom into and crop the correct location.

```
<v-image
  :config="{
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  image: image,
  shadowBlur: 5
  }"
/>
```

In the Image class there should be a property Radius. Just like in the circle class. Is their an alternative way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want rounded corners, or even a complete circle, you need to use a clipping function applied to your group or shape.

See [Konva docs example here](https://konvajs.org/docs/clipping/Clipping_Function.html)

The important part if that in the creation of your group or shape you include the definition of the clip func. The example below creates 2 overlapping circles - see the Konva docs for the working code.

```
  var group = new Konva.Group({
    clipFunc: function(ctx) {
      ctx.arc(250, 120, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx.arc(150, 120, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    }
  });
```

For rounded corners see the answer to a [similar question with a working code snippet here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028900/how-to-add-corner-radius-on-konva-group-using-clip-function/56040003#56040003)

Comment: I see you are using Vue. The links and snippets in the previous question I linked to are in plain JavaScript so you will need to interpret the answer into Vue. You'll need to add the clipfunc to your image shape object and you may be able to get away with that if your canvas is simple. If you need a combination of shape objects then you need to study the group object, and adding shapes. putting the clipfunc on the group.