# How to add border-radius to react-konva Image object?

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I have an `Image` component in `react-konva` and want to add `border-radius: 8px`. Which is the easiest way?

Answer (score 3):

Having [this amazing comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028900/how-to-add-corner-radius-on-konva-group-using-clip-function/56040003#56040003) as reference the problem can be easily solved:

```js
  ...

  <Group
    clipFunc={ctx => calcClipFunc(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius)}
  >
    <Image
      image={image}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      x={x}
      y={y}
    />
  </Group>
```

And the `calcClipFunc()` function from the previous comment:

```js
function calcClipFunc(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clip your image in Stage:

```
  // image.width, image.height
  <Stage width={200} height={200} style={{borderRadius: '8px', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
    <Layer >
      <Image image={this.state.image} />
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
```

Comment: Thanks, Babak! That could work in certain circumstances. However, I have several other layers inside my Stage component and the Image component doesn't fit the whole Stage. By bad not mentioning it earlier.